# Fatal Error on ClassLoader.php : undefined function stream_resolve_include_path()

Tags: error, installation, php, civicrm.settings.php

Has anyone received the following Fatal Error when installing CiviCRM?

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined function stream_resolve_include_path() in 
/var/www/html/devCivi/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/ClassLoader.php on line 194
```

My configuration is

- OS: Linux
- Drupal: 7.44
- CiviCRM: 4.7.12
- Php: 5.3.1

I am pretty new to all of this.

Thank you,

LAE

Comment: Just checking. What is the value of *$civicrm_root* in the civicrm.settings.php file?

Comment: I could not find the civicrm.settings.php file.  I was able to find this information in the civicrm.config.php.  Here is the information. // Load class loader
global $civicrm_root;
require_once $civicrm_root . '/CRM/Core/ClassLoader.php';
CRM_Core_ClassLoader::singleton()->register();

Comment: The *civicrm.settings.php* is created by the CiviCRM installer (see [Installing CiviCRM for Drupal 7](https://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/Installing+CiviCRM+for+Drupal+7) step 4). You are following this guide?

Comment: I was using that documentation as well.  It is Step 4 (Installing CiviCRM) where I get this error.   I have uploaded the tar.gz file and extracted it under modules as well as tried sites/all/modules.  I am sure I am missing a step. I would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1):

Your PHP version is not supported. The required PHP version is 5.5 (See [CiviCRM PHP Requirements](https://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/CiviCRM+PHP+Requirements) ). The function `stream_resolve_include_path()` was introduced in PHP 5.3.2. See [PHP.net](http://php.net/manual/en/function.stream-resolve-include-path.php) .

Comment: THANK YOU!  The Php I have is an old one: 5.3.1.  I will try to upgrade Php.